Can’t open folders or scroll or navigate
So I have a Ubuntu computer that I remotely use. I have always been able to access the file manager and click around into different folders and use it as normal. However now I cannot. It just simply won’t click into things and double clicking does nothing.
I see a lot of other people have had this issue and been able to fix it by going to Universal Access>Double click delay and toggling the settings there. However, I cannot scroll down once I’m in the settings to get to that setting. When I try to maximize the window, it gets put into two mini windows and still has the same issue. I have tried opening the settings through the terminal and tried to drag the window size to make it larger for me to access. I’ve tried purging nautilus through the terminal and I’ve tried resetting the settings. I’ve tried scrolling down using different combinations of ctrl+a up and down. I’ve also tried going into the mouse settings to change things, but the only thing that’s in there is a toggle for the left or right clicking setting.
Any help would be appreciated! Losing my mind over here 

This command sets the same setting:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse double-click 100

The range allowed in the settings slider is 100-1000ms, but it can be set to any value with commands.
